# Extend height to bottom in a container of unknown height and vertically align

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have 3 blocks of divs, side by side. The left one is an ad, the middle one is of unknown height, it could be 100px height or 1000px, and the right is also a relatively unknown height. Either of these 3 divs could be the tallest thing in the container.

Firstly, just for my own understanding, I'd like the left div to extend to the bottom of the container div.
Then I'd like the 'ad' inside 'left' to vertically align in the middle of 'left'. I'm pretty sure I how to do this if the first objective is achieved.

http://jsfiddle.net/wuo4jvwu/

```css
.container{
    background:green;
    display: inline-block;
}
.left{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    width:100px;
    background:red;
}
.ad{
    height:200px;
    width:100px;
    background:pink;
}

.middle{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    width:200px;
    background:red;
}
.right{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}

.right .news{
    background:red;
    width:inherit;
    height:200px;
}

.right .tweets{
    background:red;
    margin-top:10px;
    clear:both;
    width:inherit;
    height:100px;
}

.clear { clear: both; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="ad">AD</div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <ul>
            <li>ITEM</li>
            <li>ITEM</li>
            <li>ITEM</li>
            <li>ITEM</li>
            <li>ITEM</li>
            <li>ITEM</li>
            <li>ITEM</li>
            <li>ITEM</li>
            <li>ITEM</li>
            <li>ITEM</li>
            <li>ITEM</li>
            <li>ITEM</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="news">news</div>
        <div class="tweets">tweets</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think, there are two ways to solve this problem 1) With only css you need Flexbox 2) In other case, you need javascript to check the height of the highest column and apply this height to other column

Comment: Really? There's no other practical CSS method for doing this? If i have to use flexbox once I sort of feel like going the whole hog and using it for everything.